# Calculate the percentage of the character e in a string

Tags: c, string, word-frequency

hi so I'm trying to figure out why the percentage of e always comes up when I run my code. As you can see for the programme I need to find the number of characters and words in a string which is all good as well as the frequency of e in said string, lastly I need to find the percentage of the character e within said string. Prof said to use gets() but no other pre made functions. I of course am not asking for the answer directly but if you could point me in the right direction or where I'm going wrong it would be much appreciated (complete beginner here obviously)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char str[100];
    int i, c_number, space, c_e, percentage;

    c_number = 0;
    space = 0;
    c_e = 0;
    percentage = 0;

    printf("Enter a string: ");
    gets(str);
    for(i=0; str[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        c_number++;
        if(str[i]==' ')
        {
            space++;
        }
        if(str[i]=='e')
        {
            c_e++;
            percentage = (c_e/c_number)*100;
        }
    }
    printf("\n the number of characters is: %d and the number of words is: %d", c_number, space+1);
    printf("\n the number of e in the string is: %d", c_e);
    printf("\n the percentage of e in the string is: %d ", percentage);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Note that `percentage = (c_e/c_number)*100;` is integer division and may not produce the desired value.

Comment: Integer division truncates any fractional part, e.g. `7/4 = 1` since the answer is really 1.75, but the fractional part .75 is dropped. In your code, `c_e` is almost always be less than `c_number`, so the division returns 0, and multiplying by 100 is still 0. The solution is to multiply by 100 first, e.g. `(c_e * 100) / c_number`

Comment: You also need to compute the `percentage` *after* the loop is finished, when you have the final counts. The code currently updates `percentage` when an `e` is found. So the value in `c_number` will typically be too low (it's the count when the last `e` is found, not the total count).

Comment: Tell your professor you're not going to use `gets`. Nobody should.

Comment: "use gets()  but no other pre made functions" --> Hmm, `printf()` is a lot to replace.

Comment: Thank you everyone was able to figure it out!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) {
    const char * input = "This is a long random string that might contain a few letters.";
    
    int freq[26] = {0};
    
    
    for(char* c=input; *c; isalpha(*c) ? freq[tolower(*c++)-'a']++:c++); 

    printf("the number of characters is: %d\n", strlen(input));
    printf("the number of e in the string is: %d\n", freq['e'-'a']);
    printf("the percentage of e in the string is: %d%%\n", 100*freq['e'-'a']/strlen(input));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `"%d"` with `strlen(input)` risks undefined behavior for OP,

Comment: Hey I'm not allowed to use strlen or pointers but thanks to your code I was actually able to figure it out so thank you :) (edit: added "s" to the word pointers)